# How to know URL being observed directly in a server

Tags: networking, logs, traffic, cpanel

I host many websites using cpanel. I want to know URL being accessed at real time.

It seems that many old domains still point to my host and they seem to take a chunk of CPU

Answer (score 0):

To find out which URLs are hit, consult the logfiles of your webserver. There's a multitude of awk scripts that can help you with finding which URLs are used by clients.

Changing this won't affect CPU usage though. 100 client requests on /a/b/c likely take as much cycles as 100 requests to /d/e/f...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you run cpanel on apache, first identify the access log file configured. This would be specified in the virtual host entry for cpanel (also known as a "vhost").

next, you can simply use this command

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access_log   # replace with the proper log file
```

Tail shows the last few lines of the file, and -f tells it to wait & show new lines written to the file.

Reload your cpanel in the browser and watch the access log in real time in the terminal.